# Arrangement of $10$ people given $3$ cannot be next to each other.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Question:** How many ways can you arrange a group of $10$ students given that $3$ of them cannot sit next to each other (they cannot sit as a group of $3$ nor can $2$ of them sit next to each other $-$ the three students need to be separated completely).

**My attempt:** Naturally, I went to counting possible cases and I decided to visualise different combinations if they were arranged in a line. I ended up with $15$ combinations that they could sit in a line such that they are unique and follow the condition if each line was a circle. From there it was pretty easy to see that $\dfrac{15 \times 3! \times 7!}{10}$ was the resulting answer. I have tried to justify the $15$ without counting situations, although I have been unsuccessful. Is this answer correct? If it is, how can I properly justify it? If it isn't, how would I approach a problem like this?

Any guidances or help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I know for a fact $15$ is incorrect. I feel like it may be $12$ but still I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Are they in a line or in a circle?  If a line, then arrange the three troublesome students as $\_X\_Y\_Z\_$ and now populate those gaps. Note that the gap before $X$ and the gap after $Z$ might be empty but the internal ones can't be.  If it's a circle, it's the same only now the gap before $X$ is the same as the gap after $Z$ and it can not be empty.

Comment: Maybe you look at this problem:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774236/n-circular-arrangement-problem/3774369#3774369

Comment: Stop treating this math problem as a guessing game.  Don't put forth a number unless you have justification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Assuming they in a line, not a circle, then imagine $7$ stars a row (the "other" students). Among the $8$ gaps in between or outside of those stars, choose $3$ for the locations of the special $3$ students. This can be done in $C(8,3)=56$ ways.

(2) Now order (say, left to right) both of the two subsets of students arbitrarily, this can be done $(7!)(3!)$  ways.

Each admissible arrangement of students corresponds to a unique sequence of choices in (1) and (2). So there are $56(7!)(3!)$ ways to do it.

Comment: I upvoted.  Nice; much more elegant than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the 10 students sit in a circle thats my solution:

First lets see in how many cases $3$ of our special students sit next to each. Thats $10$.

Now we want to know in how many cases $2$ sit next to each other. If we had picked our $2$ neighboured seats then there are
$$
\frac{3!}{(3-2)!} = 6
$$
to sit our 3 students onto them.

Now to place this "double seat" we have $10$ possibilities and after we placed that one since we dont want a triple seat (we covered that case already) we have $6$ possibilities left for the third student to sit. That makes a total of $6^2 \cdot 10 = 360$ possibilities for this case.

So we got a total of $370$ 'bad' cases.

Now to sit the $3$ students down without restriction we have

$$
\frac{10!}{(10-3)!} 
$$

cases. lets substract the bad ones so we get $\frac{10!}{7!} - 370$ 'good' cases. After having sat the 3 students down according to the restriction, we can now distribute the remaining $7$ students with a total of $7!$ possibilities. So we get

$$
10! - 370\cdot 7!
$$

Answer (score -1):

The assumption in crush3dice's answer that the students sit in a circle is just as reasonable as the assumption that I am going to make, that the students sit in a row of chairs numbered, from left to right as 1, 2, ..., 10.

My approach is to **favor** brute force over elegance of thought in this one-off (small) setting.  If instead the # of chairs was (for example) 1000, then I would look for a pattern and then try for elegance.

Suppose that you select chairs 1, 3, 5, and decide that the 3 troublesome students (refer to them as a, b, and c) will sit in those 3 chairs.  There are 3! ways of permuting these 3 students among these 3 chairs and 7! ways of permuting the other 7 students among the other 7 chairs.

Therefore, the exact answer is $3! \times 7! \times T$, where $T$ represents the total # of ways of selecting 3 chairs out of 10 so that none of the three chairs is next to each other.

**Now for the brute force:**

Rather than try for elegant analysis, why not **manually** enumerate $T$.

Let $L$ = the # of the lowest of the three chairs. 
Let $M$ = the # of the middle of the three chairs. 
Let $N$ = the # of the largest of the three chairs.

Clearly, $1 \leq L \leq 6.$
That is if $L = 7$, there is no way of selecting 2 chairs among chairs 8, 9, and 10 so that the 2 chairs are apart both from each other and chair 7.

If $L$ and $M$ are set then $N$ must be in $\{(M+2), \cdots, 10\}.$

If $L$ is set, then $M$ must (similarly) be in $\{(L+2), \cdots, 8\}.$

Since you know that $L$ is in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\},$ then all you have to do to enumerate $T$ is to **count**.

**Addendum** : elegance rears its ugly head

Since the following idea just came to me, I might as well share it.  There is a shortcut to enumerating $T.$

As analyzed, $M$ must range from 3 through 8, inclusive.

For any specific $M$ in this range, $L$ must range from 1 through $M-2$ and $N$ must range from $M+2$ through 10.

Therefore, $T = \sum_{M=3}^8 \,[(M-2) \times (9-M)].$

**Addendum-2** : A symmetry argument.

By symmetry, the # of arrangements with $M=3$ equals the # of arrangements with $M=8.$  A similar argument relates $M=4$ to $M=7$ and $M=5$ to $M=6.$

Therefore, $T = 2 \times \left\{\sum_{M=3}^5 \,[(M-2) \times (9-M)]\right\}.$